# Getting value from Object using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new bee of Jquery. I am facing a problem while getting value from object.

Here is snippet that set the values and return of object.

```
expItem1 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem( {
    text : "Hello",
    key : "World"
});
```

So, when i want to get values of key from **expItem** object, So, Whenever i get value from object it says me invalid property.

```
alert(expItem1.text)
```

Any suggestion

Comment: You use a library (sap.ui.core...) wrapping basic functions and maybe also wrapping objects. You should probably look at that library's documentation.

Comment: Where's jQuery in your code?

Comment: expItem1 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem( {
    text : "Hello",
    key : "World"
});

Comment: @user1030128: That line of code does not contain any jQuery.

Comment: Yes, it is JavaScript, but it is not jQuery. jQuery is an external library primarily for DOM manipulation.

Comment: right. So any idea how to get value of key from expItem object?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs at http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ListItem.html

You should probably use [`expItem1.getKey()`](http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Item.html#getKey) and [`expItem1.getText()`](http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Item.html#getText) to get the relevant values..

Comment: Just for fun I had a look at the doc. Now I know who propagates those stupid confusions : *"It accepts one JSON-like object (object literal) as parameter"*. Sigh...

Comment: Gaby, i've tried same code but it gives me  parsedItem.getKey() is not a function :(

Comment: @user1030128: In the code in your question you named the the variable `expItem1`, not `parsedItem`.

Answer (score 0):

My be you are accessing the property in wrong way. Generally a JSON object is accesed like below:

```
var myJSON = '[{"host":"foo","url":"bar"},{"host":"foos","url":"bars"}]';
   $.each($.parseJSON(myJSON), function(key,value){
   alert("Key: "+key+" Value:"+value.url);
});
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).